# Azure SignalR Service for Multi-Tenant App

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-signalr

When building a large multi-tenant app where every tenant has its own deployment for the web application. Should they have individual Azure SignalR Instances?

Comment: How many users are you expecting per web application? Will these users be online concurrently? What type of SignalR message volume are you expecting per user? For example, is this a game where there's going to be lots of SignalR messages at once, or is this a low volume chat app where someone might send ten messages to customer support?

Comment: It isn’t a huge volume, more like a crm that just updates info when someone else updates data. If we did it on one instance , how do we make sure it only goes to each app instance

Comment: If each of your clients will have their own separate Web App, and if the number of users and messaging is low volume, I'd skip Azure SignalR Service and incorporating the SignalR package directly into your web app. It will isolate customer data. In one of my projects, we have ~6,000 concurrent users per day running off of SignalR served from our Web App.

Comment: Thanks @RobReagan that is the info I needed to know how to handle the scale. Each tenant probably will have less than 10 concurrent users

Comment: You are absolutely fine with that kind of load per tenant to host SignalR in each Web App.